# How to force java to draw swing label?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I am creating a progressBar using JLabel. Problem is when I add this label to my frame and execute some other tasks, my JFrame freezes. Is there any method like invoke and wait for swing to complete its drawing?

```
private void jButtonOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   JLabel loadingBar = new JLabel("test");
   myFrame.add(loadingBar);
   doSomeOtherTasks();
}
```

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve]? This code alone shouldn't freeze

Comment: When your UI freezes, you are doing something wrong around the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: It's not so much a matter of forcing Java to update the label as not blocking the Event Dispatch Thread from doing so by performing a long running task on the EDT. To put that another way: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I dont want to block EDT but I want to update GUI before long running function.

Comment: So implement my suggestion! I find it hard to believe you *tried what I suggested* in the 4 minutes since I posted that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //...Perform a task...
      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Comment: Without any further explanations, this isnt too helpful.

Comment: Your suggestion works perfectly but problem is after delay time it still freezes. doSomeOtherTasks() method takes nearly 5 seconds.

Comment: you need to force the Timer to stop ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();